# Merge and create a new JSON array of all the records with same id

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have to merge and create a JSON array of all the records having same cluster_id within a list of dictionary. For example: id: 1 & 2 has same cluster_id field so they should be merged as shown in expected output and 3 fields id,name,match_full_address should be shown as JSON array for the new field record and same for the singleton record with id 3.

My Dictionary list:

```
[{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Will Smith',
    'match_full_address': 'Ridge Boulevard,123 Main Street,Branchburg,NJ',
    'cluster_id': 91,
    'lat': 18756.73,
    'longi': -97.395351,
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Sandra Bullock',
    'match_full_address': 'New Castle,123 Mountain Ave,Branchburg,NJ',
    'cluster_id': 91,
    'lat': 18756.73,
    'longi': -97.395351,
},
{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Tom Cruise',
    'match_full_address': 'MI2, 123 Syracuse Avenue, Branchburg,NJ',
    'cluster_id': 92,
    'lat': 18756.73,
    'longi': -97.395351,
}
]
```

**Expected Output**:

```
[{
    'cluster_id': 91,
    'lat': 18756.73,
    'longi': -97.395351,
        'records': [{'id': 1,
    'name': 'Will Smith',
    'match_full_address': 'Ridge Boulevard,123 Main Street,Branchburg,NJ'},
    {'id': 2,
    'name': 'Sandra Bullock',
    'match_full_address': 'New Castle,123 Mountain Ave,Branchburg,NJ'}]
},
{
    'cluster_id': 92,
    'lat': 18756.73,
    'longi': -97.395351,
 'records': [{  'id': 3,
    'name': 'Tom Cruise',
    'match_full_address': 'MI2, 123 Syracuse Avenue, Branchburg,NJ'}
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temporary dict to keep track of the records of the same `cluster_id` and keep appending the keys of interest to the records.

Assuming your list of dicts is stored in variable `l`:

```
t = {}
for d in l:
    if d['cluster_id'] not in t:
        t[d['cluster_id']] = {k: d.get(k, []) for k in ('cluster_id', 'lat', 'longi', 'records')}
    t[d['cluster_id']]['records'].append({k: d[k] for k in ('id', 'name', 'match_full_address')})
```

`list(t.values())` would return:

```
[{'cluster_id': 91,
  'lat': 18756.73,
  'longi': -97.395351,
  'records': [{'id': 1,
               'match_full_address': 'Ridge Boulevard,123 Main '
                                     'Street,Branchburg,NJ',
               'name': 'Will Smith'},
              {'id': 2,
               'match_full_address': 'New Castle,123 Mountain '
                                     'Ave,Branchburg,NJ',
               'name': 'Sandra Bullock'}]},
 {'cluster_id': 92,
  'lat': 18756.73,
  'longi': -97.395351,
  'records': [{'id': 3,
               'match_full_address': 'MI2, 123 Syracuse Avenue, Branchburg,NJ',
               'name': 'Tom Cruise'}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of questions are quite common. The answer is always: `sorted`+[`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
def cluster_id_key(record):
    return record['cluster_id']

def process(data):
    sorted_data = sorted(data, key=cluster_id_key)
    for cluster_id, records in groupby(sorted_data, key=cluster_id_key):
        records = list(records)
        common_props = [k for k,v records[0].items() if all(v==r[k] for r in records)]
        cluster_data = {k: v for k,v in records[0].items() if k in common_props}
        reduced_records = [{k:v for k,v in record.items() if k not in common_props} for record in records]
        yield {**cluster_data 'records': reduced_records}
```

---

The solution above handles the case where properties like `lat` may not be the same for all the elements in a cluster. In that case it automatically inserts `lat` inside the `records` array instead of at the cluster level. Also if the same value is common to all records it is put outside `records`.

I'll live it as an exercise to tweak it to obtain exactly the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

While you still can use comprehensions, I don't think its a good case for that. So just simple reiterate though your list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json


listM = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Will Smith',
    'match_full_address': 'Ridge Boulevard,123 Main Street,Branchburg,NJ',
    'cluster_id': 91,
    'lat': 18756.73,
    'longi': -97.395351,
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Sandra Bullock',
    'match_full_address': 'New Castle,123 Mountain Ave,Branchburg,NJ',
    'cluster_id': 91,
    'lat': 18756.73,
    'longi': -97.395351,
},
{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Tom Cruise',
    'match_full_address': 'MI2, 123 Syracuse Avenue, Branchburg,NJ',
    'cluster_id': 92,
    'lat': 18756.73,
    'longi': -97.395351,
}
]

clusters = dict()
for item in listM:
    data = clusters.get(item['cluster_id'], {})
    if len(data) == 0:
        data["cluster_id"] = item["cluster_id"]
        data["lat"] = item["lat"]
        data["long"] = item["longi"]
        data["records"] = []

    data["records"].append(
        dict({
            'id': item['id'],
            'name': item['name'],
            'match_full_address': item['match_full_address']
            })
        )
    clusters.update({ item['cluster_id']: data })

print(list(clusters.values()))
```